# Does RAID1 really protect me?

Tags: raid, software-raid

I have 2 drives mirroring each other. They are pluggable and occupying 2 SATA slots. Totally I have 5 SATA slots. Can I freely unplug RAID parts and then plug them back and have data intact?

If not then what is the purpose of RAID1?

Comment: be sure to check your controllers help documents. for many of them breaking a mirror and recreating it is a non-trivial operation, so you may not be able to just plug your second pane back in and have it connect as a mirror. Raid1 is a truly redundant architechure though, so if you do unplug it, your system will be fine. just don't do it often, as repair may be expensive.

Answer (score 3):

RAID 1 is for redundancy in case of a hardware failure: the cable, the power, or the disk can die, and you'll still have (at least) one full, complete copy of your data.

If you want to unplug and move the hard drive *while the computer is running*, you need to make sure your hard disk controller can handle it, as well as your motherboard and hard drive. But as soon as this happens, that disk is treated as a missing drive, and will need to be resynced before it can be used again.

If you want to move the drive cable while the computer is *off*, most (but not all!) controllers will recognize the drive, and continue operation as though nothing happened.

Here is a quick description, using pictures:

[image]

Comment: Suppose my controller allows hot unplug. Since unplug is indistinguishable from hardware failure, RAID should allow me to unplug, right?

Comment: Nice pics by the way :)

Comment: Correct, but it'll see the disk as a new disk sometimes. Either way it needs to re synchronize the data before it's back in the array

Comment: I'm going to try those pictures at work on Monday.. I hope RAID 0+1 gives us faster data flow because at the moment I have to wait ages just to get a friggin' cup of water...

Comment: We use raid 10 on our servers, and it's great for our 400 employees

Comment: If this is the answer for you, there is a green check mark that makes me better than the others... Just saying :P